# How to validate multiple entities against themselves as well as against existing rows in the database?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

I have an application where I need to validate business hours to make sure they don't overlap in CakePHP 3. All records can be changed in a single form. The data looks somewhat like this:

| id | day | opening_time | closing_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 08:00:00 | 13:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 16:00:00 | 22:00:00 |

Now when I change the first opening_time to 17:00 that would be invalid, because it would overlap with the second row. But when I change the second opening_time to 18:00 in the same form it should be valid.

I tried to use buildRules:

```
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['store_id'], 'Stores'));

    $rules->add(
        function (BusinessHour $entity, array $options): bool {
            $conditions = [
                'id !=' => $entity->id,
                'store_id' => $entity->store_id,
                'day' => $entity->day,
                'OR' => [
                    [
                        'opening_time <=' => $entity->opening_time,
                        'closing_time >=' => $entity->opening_time,
                    ],
                    [
                        'opening_time <=' => $entity->closing_time,
                        'closing_time >=' => $entity->closing_time,
                    ],
                    [
                        'opening_time >=' => $entity->opening_time,
                        'opening_time <=' => $entity->closing_time,
                    ],
                    [
                        'closing_time >=' => $entity->opening_time,
                        'closing_time <=' => $entity->closing_time,
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            return !$options['repository']->exists($conditions);
        },
        'overlapping',
        [
            'errorField' => 'opening_time',
            'message' => __('Business hours may not overlap.'),
        ]
    );

    return $rules;
}
```

But it checks the first record against the data in the database and marks is as invalid even though the change of the second row would make it valid. For example when the data in the database is as mentioned above and I have the following post data it should be valid but isn't.

```
$data['business_hours'] = [
    (int) 0 => [
        'day' => '0',
        'opening_time' => [
            'hour' => '16',
            'minute' => '30'
        ],
        'closing_time' => [
            'hour' => '17',
            'minute' => '00'
        ]
    ],
    (int) 1 => [
        'day' => '0',
        'opening_time' => [
            'hour' => '18',
            'minute' => '00'
        ],
        'closing_time' => [
            'hour' => '20',
            'minute' => '00'
        ]
    ],
];
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: So what's the problem with your code? Your question doesn't really point to anything specific. Or more specifically, is your problem with the query not obtaining the correct results, or is it with what happens afterwards, ie "marking things invalid"? Or maybe both?

Comment: @ndm Thanks pointing that out. I tried to clarify my question. The query gets the correct results, but it checks a single entry against the database and doesn't take the other changes into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically you can only save one entity at a time, not only on application level, but also on DBMS level, so the rule is correct in telling you that the data is not valid, as it only validates one entity at a time.

I think you'd either need some kind of state to handle this, or you'd need kind of a mix of what validation and application rules are ment for, ie you'd need to validate stateless data as well as stateful/persisted data, not only do all hours in the unpersisted dataset need to be valid with respect to each other, they also need to be valid with respect to the already persisted data in the database.

There's lots of room to argue how to best solve this I guess, there's no interface yet in application rules that would allow to validate multiple entities, so however you solve the problem, it would probably be some kind of compromise/workaround one way or another.

Since this is finally about data in the DB, all validation should happen in a transaction, so keeping things in the applications rules would be prefereable I guess. One dirty way I could think of, would be to pass the IDs of all entities into the saving process, and in your rule exclude all IDs that haven't been checked (and therefore saved) *yet*, that way subsequent checks would run against previous entities that have already been persisted, meaning in the end you'd have checked all records for validity against each other.

Here's an example - I don't know your association setup, so I'll just assume that you're saving `Stores` with associated `BusinessHours`, the exact setup doesn't really matter, though, it should just show how to build and pass in the custom options:

```php
// ...
$store = $this->Stores->patchEntity($store, $this->request->getData());
$businessHourIds = new \ArrayObject(
    collection($store->business_hours)
        ->extract('id')
        ->filter()
        ->indexBy(function ($value) {
            return $value;
        })
        ->toArray()
);
// $businessHourIds would represent an array like this, where both
// the key and the value would hold the ID: [1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, ...]
if ($this->Stores->save($sore, ['businessHourIds' => $businessHourIds])) {
    // ...
}
// ...
```

It's important that it's an `ArrayObject` instance, so that its state will persist accross the multiple different `save()` calls for each business hour entity. Your rule could then do something along the lines of this:

```php
function (BusinessHour $entity, array $options): bool {
    if (!isset($options['businessHourIds'])) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // If the entity isn't new, its ID must be present in the IDs list
    // so that it can be excluded in the exists check
    if (
        !$entity->isNew() &&
        !isset($options['businessHourIds'][$entity->id]
    ) {
        return false;
    }

    // the current entries opening time must be smaller than its closing time
    if ($entity->opening_time >= $entity->closing_time) {
        return false;
    }

    $conditions = [
        'id NOT IN' => (array)$options['businessHourIds'],
        'store_id' => $entity->store_id,
        'day' => $entity->day,
        'closing_time >' => $entity->opening_time,
        'opening_time <' => $entity->closing_time,
    ];
    
    // remove the current entity ID from the list, so that for the next
    // check it is not being excluded, meaning that all following business
    // hours will have to be valid according to this entity's data
    unset($options['businessHourIds'][$entity->id]);

    return !$options['repository']->exists($conditions);
}
```

So this is untested, ideally it would work, but it's primarily ment to illustrate what I'm talking about. Also note that I've reduced the open/closing time conditions, assuming that the closing time must be greater than the opening time, this check should theoretically cover all possible overlaps.